# Why can't I use "mkdir" with a Pathname object?

Tags: ruby

I've recently been trying out the Pathname lib, and one thing I want to do is use `mkdir` to create some directories.

I looked up the documentation and it says it wraps up `mkdir` but everytime I try to use it I`m getting this error:

```
irb(main):006:0> p = Pathname.new('/tmp')
=> #<Pathname:/tmp>
irb(main):007:0> a = p.mkdir("123adam")
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:975:in `mkdir'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:975:in `mkdir'
  from (irb):7
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1589
```

Can anyone explain what I`m doing wrong here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the directory you want to create with Pathname and then call `mkdir`.

This should work:

```
p = Pathname.new('/tmp/123adam')
p.mkdir
```

The argument you can supply are the permissions for the new directory.

Comment: Alternatively: `(p + "123adam").mkdir`

Answer (score 2):

Out of interest, the reason why you get "can't convert String into Integer" is because `Pathname.mkdir` is actually a wrapper around `Dir.mkdir` as follows:

```
def mkdir(*args) Dir.mkdir(@path, *args) end
```

The path represented by the `Pathname` object is passed as the first parameter to `Dir.mkdir`, followed by any parameters passed to `Pathname.mkdir`. The second parameter for `Dir.mkdir` is the numeric access permissions that you would like the directory created to have. Hence in your example `"123adam"` is being passed to `Dir.mkdir` where a number is expected.